# Is it possible to clone git repo with out sub modules?

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration

I am trying to on board git repo to CI. But looks like the this repo uses the sub module from another repo and then eventually fails to clone the project because of permission denial from other repo. Is it possible to clone git repo with out sub modules?

Comment: What CI tool? It is probably the CI tool that is doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In version 1.1.13 of the Git Plugin for Jenkins, the ability to ignore submodules if needed was added. https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-6658

Answer (score 1):

You can actually make it work by changing either the hosts file or the ssh config to point to a server where you have this repo within your organization.

Comment: ya I indeed added deploy key to the repo which is to be cloned by CI but. I also tried to add same deploy to to other repo but looks like deploy key has to be unique

Comment: You can present a different key too.

Comment: key generation is not under my control. we are using CloudBees and it generates only one key. This is my understanding, I might be wrong though